# How to make JButton open a JFrame?

Tags: java, eclipse, jframe, jbutton

I am trying to code a software that has several JButtons and once clicked opens another JFrame page. I have looked at many other posts but could not really find anything that I could understand, or something that would work. Could someone please tell me a way to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize another JFrame when the button click event is called!

For example:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Click");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        new OtherFrame();
    }
}
```

And then you have a class (in this case OtherFrame):

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class OtherFrame {
    private JFrame frame;

    public OtherFrame() {
        this.frame = new JFrame("Window");
        // Do whatever you need to do
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds, cool! But then if I want to export the code into an application how would I do that would two classes?

Comment: If you are using an IDE, it should be pretty straight forward. If you are compiling via javac command, you need to add a classpath argument: `javac -classpath "." YourClass.java`. The . is the relative path to the current directory. You can change this to where ever the files are located.

Comment: Or do you think I can but the code that you recommended in the same class, and do another method?? Or something like that. Thank You So Much For The Help!

Comment: Yeah you can do it in the same class, in a method. You can also use a inner class.

Comment: Hey there! I tried out your code but I am having a couple problems!

Comment: I can't post my code because it goes over the limit of characters